# Ubuntu: Automount /etc/fstab with mount -a, does it disrupt already mounted devices?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, mount, fstab

Say I have `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` already mounted and I am currently copying files from one to the other. Can I safely edit `/etc/fstab` to also include yet unmounted `/dev/sdd` and do `mount -a` to mount it? Or is there a risk that a process working on the other already mounted drives will be disrupted? (I.e. will those be unmounted and remounted in the process, or is `mount -a` clever enough to just ignore them?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mount -a` command will detect already mounted filesystems, according to its man page. So running it after editing `/etc/fstab` shouldn't do any harm to the already mounted partitions.